# How to insert into oracle custom object from select result?

Tags: oracle

I have a obj like below

```sql
CREATE TYPE SOME_CUSTOM_OBJ FORCE AS OBJECT(
   ID number,
   Name varchar(30)
)
```

and want to insert value in that, I read the document for oracle database, but only way that I found is use initial function.

```
DECLARE
  SOME_OBJ SOME_CUSTOM_OBJ;
BEGIN
  SOME_OBJ := SOME_CUSTOM_OBJ(1,'PETER');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SOME_OBJECT.ID);
END;

// OUTPUT : 1
```

I want to insert those value from another table, the imagine like below

```
DECLARE
  SOME_OBJECT SOME_CUSTOM_OBJECT;
BEGIN
  SOME_OBJECT := SOME_CUSTOM_OBJECT(
  SELECT ID,NAME FROM ANTHER_TABLE WHERE {SOME CONDITIONS} AND rownum = 1
);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SOME_OBJECT.ID);
END;
// OUTPUT : 1
```

The value who select from table would be only 1 row.

If use Object_table could be easy to solve my question, but I don't want to add too much things in the database.

Comment: `select type_constructor(arg1 => value1, arg2 => value2) from your_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the object constructor in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
DECLARE
  SOME_OBJECT SOME_CUSTOM_OBJ;
BEGIN
  SELECT some_custom_obj(ID,NAME)
  INTO   some_object
  FROM   another_table
  WHERE  rownum = 1;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SOME_OBJECT.ID);
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE another_table (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f68df3e6a76e9e20a8a32dff9b8829c)*